# How to use vue-router with vue-touch-events

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I tried to use `vue-router` with `vue-touch-events` this way:

```
<i v-touch="go('home')" class="fas fa-bars"></i>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "Nav",
    methods: {
      go: function(state) {
        this.$router.push(state)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

This does not work as `go('home')` is executed every time the view renders and not on touch/tap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `v-touch` value must be a function; `go('home')` will be called immediately and returns `undefined` which is not a function.

Try this instead:

```
<i v-touch="() => go('home')" class="fas fa-bars"></i>
```

`v-on` is the only directive that accepts the syntax you used; the Vue template compiler will not wrap your expression in a function for other directives which is why you must do it manually.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work but transitions triggered by `computed` properties and bound via `v-bind:class` no seem to be broken.

Comment: That's a separate unrelated issue.

Comment: Yes, I guess that makes sense.

Comment: @DecadeMoon Probably you'd like to add this link: [Vue Github Issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5588)

Comment: Fixed the `push` / `v-bind:class` issue: `this.$router.push({ name: state })`